# problem with cooley-tukey FFT algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, fft, complex-numbers

I've recently learned about the Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm. I want to gain a deeper understanding of this algorithm and thus decided to write my own (non-recursive) implementation of it. However I can't get it to work. I've been messing with it for a few days but it just won't give a good output.

The output splits the DFT into even and odd DFTs and does this recursively until the DFTs consist of just a single data point.

I combine the N DFTs from the ground up with twiddle factors, for every frequency to get the complete DFT.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Using numpy to work with complex numbers
import numpy as np

def twiddle(k,bits):
    #Generate twiddle factors for a frequency
    N=2**bits
    T=[]
    sign=1
    for i in range(bits):
        #Check if the frequency is in the upper or lower half of the range
        if k>=N//2:
            k-=N//2
            sign=-1
        
        #Generate complex twiddle factor for every stage of the algorithm
        temp=sign*np.exp(-1j*math.tau*k/N)
        
        T.append(temp)
        
        N=N//2
        sign=1
    return T
    
def FFT(data,bits):
    #Slice data to ensure its length is always a power of 2
    N=2**bits
    data=data[:N]
    
    F=[]
    #Calculate Fourier coefficient for every frequency
    for k in range(N):
        #Obtain twiddle factors for frequency
        T=twiddle(k,bits)
        
        #Copy input data into temporary array
        temp=[x for x in data]
        
        #Run through all stages
        for i in range(bits):
            #Combine even and odd partial DFT's with twiddle factor
            temp=[temp[2*j]+T[bits-i-1]*temp[2*j+1] for j in range(2**(bits-i-1))]
            
        F.append(temp[0])
    return F
     
#Generate some input data   
bits=10
t=range(0,2**bits)
f=300
samplerate=5000
v=[10*math.sin(math.tau*f*x/samplerate) for x in t]

f=[samplerate*i*2**(-bits) for i in range(2**bits)]

#Run function and plot
F=FFT(v,bits)
F=np.array(F)

plt.plot(f,abs(F))
```

To give an idea here is the [the plot this code yields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImdRf.png). Obviously since the input is a single 300Hz sinewave it should only return one peak at 300, which is then mirrored in the Nyquist frequency.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure I've overlooked something or am just not using the right method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot about a [bit-reversal permutaion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation). Radix-2|4|8 FFT algorithm is supposed to operate in-place and to do so it requires the values to be in a bit-reversed order.
Also, if you gonna dig deeper and to implement mixed-radix algorithm which is a generalization of Cooley-Tukey algorithm then you will need to implement a mixed-radix reversal as well